# Play framework: file download

Tags: android, playframework, playframework-2.0

I try to make a file server to let people download APK file.My server is using Play framework.
the problem is :I always download a "app" file without file extension by PC browser.while using android browser,  I always download a "app.bin" file. Is there anything wrong with my code?

test link:[test download](http://elv.locky.jp/app)

```
public static Result get_app() {

    File tmp = new File("Ele.apk"); 
    response().setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Ele.apk");
    response().setContentType("mime/type");
    return ok(tmp);
}`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such Content-Type as `mime/type` or `mime/apk` as you trying to use it in the sample...

By [Wikipedia description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APK_%28file_format%29) APK's Content-Type is `application/vnd.android.package-archive` and probably this one you should set.

If problem remains try to google what is valid Content-Type for serving these keys.